# How do I centre everything on my page?

Tags: css

This is my first website I have ever created and is my 4th day of programming therefore, if my coding structure is bad I apologies.

I was wondering if anyone could me because, when I look at my webpage preview on codepen certain text, buttons etc doesn't look to be centred. I was wondering if anyone could him me centre the button, and the arrow. If they're centred in your opinion can you help me centre the "Liam digital portfolio text."

Is there a command that centres everything you want?

[My codepen.](http://codepen.io/ldocherty1/pen/EZLOdP)

I'm aware the follow tag centres what you want. However, is there a command which centres everything u specify?

```
 <centre>
```

Kind Regards, 
Liam.

Comment: Actually, the tag is `<center>`.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to center everything on the entire page would be to change your `<body>` tag to:

```
<body style="text-align:center">
```